# How to ignore some fields in API response - Retrofit @GET

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gson, retrofit

I have a get API call. and the response is like this:

```
  {
      "id": "22222",
      "resourceUri": "ssss",
      "xxx": null,
      "xxx": [],
      "phone": "kkk",
      "email": "jjjjjj",
   }
```

out of all these fields, I only need the ID. SO, I've created a class like this:

```
data class ApiResponse(
    val id: String,
)
```

and api calls is like this:

```
suspend fun apiCall(@Header("Authorization") authorization : String) :Response<ApiResponse>
```

It doesn't work and it throws an error. What can I do?

Comment: Some api can do that but just don't use what you don't want.  I'm not going to change my api for you.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be nothing wrong for the implementation you provide. Your `ApiResponse` class can have less attributes than your response JSON.

If possible, please further provide the Exception you encounter.

I have a little example below for your reference:
`Main.kt`

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://localhost")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build()
  val retromock = Retromock.Builder().retrofit(retrofit).build()

  runBlocking {
    val service = retromock.create(TestCall::class.java)
    val response = service.apiCall()
    println(response.body())
  }
}
```

`ApiResponse.kt`

```kotlin
data class ApiResponse(
  val id: String,
  val name: String,
  val remark: String,
) {
  override fun toString(): String {
    return "ID: $id | Name: $name | remark: $remark"
  }
}
```

`TestCall.kt`

```kotlin
interface TestCall {
  @Mock
  @MockResponse(body = "{\"id\":\"1\", \"name\":\"Smith\", \"age\":30, \"score\":20, \"remark\":null}")
  @GET("/")
  suspend fun apiCall() : Response<ApiResponse>
}
```

And the output can be printed without errors:

```
ID: 1 | Name: Smith | remark: null
```

So in the above example, you can see that the returning JSON contains attributes like `age`, `score`, which are not included in `ApiResponse`. So you may have to check other configuration that causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, Your API response is correct. you can create a response with the needed data only.

```
data class ApiResponse(
    val id: String,
)
```

your error may be something else please share your logcat error, it might be understood the error